# How to validate an method argument with @Validated annotation based on group

Tags: java, spring, validation

I have an entity `XYZ.java`

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class XYZ extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

  @NotNull (groups = {Groups.Insert.class, Groups.Delete.class, Groups.Update.class, Groups.Select.class})
  private String X;
```

and there is an interface `XYZCRUD.java`to do CRUD operations on `XYZ.java`

```
@Validated
public interface XYZCRUD {

  public int insert(@Valid XYZ entity) throws SomeException;
```

Although javax's @Valid works for @NotNull validation but it does not support passing validation group as annotation attribute from the method from where i am triggering the validation .
So I tried using @Validated annotation which does allow to pass groups via an attribute  "value"  like this

```
@Validated
public interface XYZCRUD {

      public int insert(@Validated(value=SomeGroup.class) XYZ entity) throws SomeException;
```

However it does not trigger the validation at all.I tried after removing the groups attribute from the field and also from the trigger annotation.

***Conclusion :*** @Validated does not trigger @NotNull

***Questions :***

1. Why @Validated does not trigger the javax's @NotNull ? Am I doing something
       wrong or does it not support it?
2. Is there any any other way? cannot implement custom validator

***NOTE :*** I am also using lombok if it has something to do with this.

Comment: See examples: https://narmo7.wordpress.com/2014/04/26/how-to-set-up-validation-group-in-springmvc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like @Validated was doing its job which is only to mark "parameters" with groups but how is that interpreted ("intercepted") by validation framework is a different story .
In my case this is what was happening when method level validation were being intercerpted and validated

**From the docs of Spring's MethodValidationInterceptor**

> Validation groups can be specified through Spring's Validated annotation at the type level of the containing target class, applying to all public service methods of that class. By default, JSR-303 will validate against its default group only.

Which means the **ONLY** groups mentioned at class level will be validated and they will be used  for **all public methods**.

```
@Validated(value=SomeGroup.class)//this will be used as group for all methods being validated
public interface XYZCRUD {

public int insert(@Valid XYZ entity) throws SomeException;
public int delete(@Valid XYZ entity) throws SomeException;
```

I do not understand the reason for such implementation but this is what the docs say .If someone knows the reason please comment.

Answer (score 4):

@mayank-vats If you want to apply a group to specific method (not all public methods), you can use:

```java
@Validated
public class MyClass {

    @Validated({Group1.class})
    public myMethod1(@Valid Foo foo) { ... }

    @Validated({Group2.class})
    public myMethod2(@Valid Foo foo) { ... }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For @NotNull, you'll need to add the defgault group:

```
@Validated({ Default.class, Group1.class })
public myMethod1(@NotNull @Valid Foo foo) { ... }
```