# How to use validation groups in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

I have a DTO, which will be used by 2 endpoints.

The two endpoints -

1. /groupA
2. /groupB

Consider the DTO with two fields, say fieldA and fieldB.

For /groupA, fieldA shouldn't be blank and fieldB can be blank
For /groupB, fieldB shouldn't be blank and fieldA can be blank

I understand that this can be achieved by validation groups. I created two interfaces GroupA and GroupB.

```
public interface GroupA {
}

public interface GroupB {
}

public class RequestDto {
  @NotBlank(groups = GroupA.class)
  private String fieldA;

  @NotBlank(groups = GroupB.class)
  private String fieldB;
}
```

In the controller, I used @Validated annotation:

```
public ResponseEntity<ResponseDto> getResult(@Validated(GroupA.class                             @RequestBody @Validated RequestDto request)) {

...

}
```

If I do not pass fieldA in request body, I expect the endpoint to give 400 BAD REQUEST. However, it is not functioning as expected. It is returning 200 OK response.

What am I missing ? This is the first time I'm using validation groups, so might have missed something.

I appreciate all the help!

Comment: Does validation work at all? I doubt it and I suspect you only have the validation API on your class path and not an implementation. Did you include `spring-boot-starter-validation` as your dependency, if not add it and remove what you have now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate an method argument with @Validated annotation based on group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31826981/how-to-validate-an-method-argument-with-validated-annotation-based-on-group)